# drawing minmal DFA for the given regular expression

Tags: regular-language, dfa, nfa

What is the direct and easy approach to draw minimal `DFA`, that accepts the same language as of given `Regular Expression(RE)`.
I know it can be done by:

```
Regex ---to----► NFA ---to-----► DFA ---to-----► minimized DFA
```

But is there any shortcut way? like for `(a+b)*ab`

Comment: I don't think there is a shortcut.

Comment: I think there are some algorithms as mentioned in "compilers: principles, techniqes and tools" by AHO, SETHI & ULLMAN. the author(s) has written a technique to construct a dfa directly from a regular expression". But I couldn't understand it.

Comment: @NirajRana give me the link ..which topic you are talking about

Answer (score 13):

### Regular Expression to DFA

Although there is NO algorithmic shortcut  to draw DFA from a Regular Expression(RE) but a shortcut technique is possible by analysis not by derivation, it can save your time to draw a minimized dfa. But off-course the technique you can learn only by practice. I take your example to show my approach:

```
(a + b)*ab
```

First, think about the language  of the regular expression. If its difficult to sate what is the language description at first attempt, then find what is the smallest possible strings can be  generate in language then find second smallest.....

Keep memorized solution of some basic regular expressions. For example, I have [written here some basic idea to writing left-linear and right-linear grammars directly from regular expression.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816439/left-linear-and-right-linear-grammars/13945932#13945932) Similarly you can write for construing minimized dfa.

In RE  `(a + b)*ab`, the smallest possible string is `ab` because using `(a + b)*` one can generate `NULL(^)` string. Second smallest string can be either `aab` or `bab`. Now one thing we can easily notice about language is that any string in language of this RE always ends with `ab` (suffix), Whereas prefix can be any possible string consist of `a` and `b` including `^`.

Also, if current symbol is `a`; then one possible chance is that next symbol would be a  `b` and string end. Thus in dfa we required, a transition such that when ever a  `b` symbol  comes *after* symbol `a`, then it should be move to some of the **final state** in dfa.

Next, if a new symbol comes on final state then we should move to some *non-final* state because any symbol after `b` is possible only in middle of some string in language as all language string terminates with suffix `'ab'`.

So with this knowledge at this stage we can draw an incomplete transition diagram like below:

> --►(Q<sub>0</sub>)---a---►(Q<sub>1</sub>)---b----►((Q<sub>f</sub>))

Now at this point you need to understand: every state has some meaning for example

> (Q<sub>0</sub>) means =  Start state
>   (Q<sub>1</sub>) means =  Last symbol was 'a', and with one more 'b' we can shift to a final state
>   (Q<sub>f</sub>)  means  =  Last two symbols was 'ab'

Now think what happens if a symbol `a` comes on final state. Just more to state Q<sub>1</sub> because this state means last symbol was `a`. (*updated transition diagram*)

```
--►(Q0)---a---►(Q1)---b----►((Qf))  
                ▲-----a--------|
```

But suppose instead of symbol `a` a symbol `b` comes at final state. Then we should move from final state to some non-final state. In present transition graph  in this situation we should make a move to initial state from final state Q<sub>f</sub>.(*as again we need `ab` in  string for acceptation*)

```
--►(Q0)---a---►(Q1)---b----►((Qf))  
     ▲          ▲-----a--------|  
     |----------------b--------|
```

This graph is still incomplete! because there is no outgoing edge for symbol `a` from Q<sub>1</sub>. And for symbol `a` on state Q<sub>1</sub>  a self loop is required because Q<sub>1</sub> means last symbol was an `a`.

```
                a-  
                ||
                ▼|
--►(Q0)---a---►(Q1)---b----►((Qf))  
     ▲          ▲-----a--------|  
     |----------------b--------|
```

Now I believe all possible out-going edges are present from Q<sub>1</sub> & Q<sub>f</sub> in above graph. One missing edge is an out-going edge from Q<sub>0</sub> for symbol `b`. And there must be a self loop at state Q<sub>0</sub> because again we need a sequence of `ab` so that string can be accept. (*from Q<sub>0</sub> to Q<sub>f</sub> shift is possible with `ab`*)

```
    b-          a-  
    ||          ||
    ▼|          ▼|
--►(Q0)---a---►(Q1)---b----►((Qf))  
     ▲          ▲-----a--------|  
     |----------------b--------|
```

Now DFA is complete!

Off-course the method might look difficult at first few tries. But if you learn to draw this way you will observe improvement in your analytically skills. And you will find this method is quick and objective way to draw DFA.

<sub>* In the link I given,  I described some more regular expressions, I would highly encourage you to learn them and try to make DFA for those regular expressions too.</sub>

Comment: Find some more examples in **EDIT** section of [**my answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816439/left-linear-and-right-linear-grammars?answertab=votes#tab-top) I draw with same technique.

Comment: Grijesh bhai I need your help. Suggest me a good book for Automata Theory.

Comment: @haccks  [Peter Linz](http://www.flipkart.com/introduction-formal-languages-automata-4th/p/itmdfjfnkvmpnabu) is comparatively simple book, good for students

Comment: [An Introduction To Formal Languages And Automata](http://www.flipkart.com/introduction-formal-languages-automata-4th/p/itmdfjfnkvmpnabu)

Comment: What about *Theory of Computation by K.L.P Mishra* and *Automata theory by Ullman & Hopcraft* ?

Comment: @haccks "Ullman & Hopcraft" is tough and takes time to read at first. "K.L.P Mishra" is ok ok, doesn't explain much, looks like written by mathematician. A Computer Science student will like "Peter Linz" I think so. Btw I read all 3. [Video lectures](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7716/can-someone-give-a-simple-but-non-toy-example-of-a-context-sensitive-grammar/7717#7717)

Comment: @haccks I have answered almost on every basic topics, Some of them I have linked @ my profile too

Comment: @haccks Very good videos but for advance topics from TM onward: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oF92Z7qVivs

Comment: @haccks Check [this book](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=RSODknf4pyIC&pg=PA68&lpg=PA68&dq=(na(w)+-+nb(w))) Look good