# Left-Linear and Right-Linear Grammars

Tags: grammar, regular-language, computation-theory, formal-languages

I need help with constructing a left-linear and right-linear grammar for the languages below?

```
a)  (0+1)*00(0+1)*
b)  0*(1(0+1))*
c)  (((01+10)*11)*00)*
```

For a) I have the following:

```
Left-linear
S --> B00 | S11
B --> B0|B1|011

Right-linear
S --> 00B | 11S
B --> 0B|1B|0|1
```

Is this correct? I need help with b & c.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

### Constructing an equivalent Regular Grammar from a Regular Expression

First, I start with some simple rules to construct Regular Grammar(RG) from Regular Expression(RE).
I am writing rules for Right Linear Grammar (leaving as an exercise to write similar rules for Left Linear Grammar)

**NOTE:** Capital letters are used for variables, and small for terminals in grammar. NULL symbol is `^`. Term *'any number'* means zero or more times that is * star closure.

[**BASIC IDEA**]

- **SINGLE TERMINAL:** If the RE is simply `e (e being any terminal)`, we can write `G`, with only one production rule `S --> e` (where `S is the start symbol`), is an equivalent RG.
- **UNION OPERATION:** If the RE is of the form `e + f`, where both `e and f are terminals`, we can write  `G`, with two production rules `S --> e | f`, is an equivalent RG.
- **CONCATENATION:**  If the RE is of the form `ef`, where both `e and f are terminals`, we can write  `G`, with two production rules `S --> eA, A --> f`, is an equivalent RG.
- **STAR CLOSURE:** If the RE is of the form `e*`, where `e  is a terminal` and `*  Kleene star closure` operation, we can write two production rules in `G`, `S --> eS | ^`, is an equivalent RG.
- **PLUS CLOSURE:** If the RE is of the form e<sup>+</sup>, where `e  is a terminal` and `+  Kleene plus closure` operation, we can write two production rules in `G`, `S --> eS | e`, is an equivalent RG.
- **STAR CLOSURE ON UNION:**  If the RE is of the form (e + f)*, where both `e and f are terminals`, we can write three production rules in `G`, `S --> eS | fS | ^`, is an equivalent RG.
- **PLUS CLOSURE ON UNION:**  If the RE is of the form (e + f)<sup>+</sup>, where both `e and f are terminals`, we can write four production rules in `G`, `S --> eS | fS | e | f`, is an equivalent RG.
- **STAR CLOSURE ON CONCATENATION:**  If the RE is of the form (ef)*, where both `e and f are terminals`, we can write three production rules in `G`, `S --> eA | ^, A --> fS`, is an equivalent RG.
- **PLUS CLOSURE ON CONCATENATION:**  If the RE is of the form (ef)<sup>+</sup>, where both `e and f are terminals`, we can write three production rules in `G`, `S --> eA, A --> fS | f`, is an equivalent RG.

Be sure that you understands all above rules, here is the summary table:

```
+-------------------------------+--------------------+------------------------+
| TYPE                          | REGULAR-EXPRESSION | RIGHT-LINEAR-GRAMMAR   |
+-------------------------------+--------------------+------------------------+
| SINGLE TERMINAL               | e                  | S --> e                |
| UNION OPERATION               | e + f              | S --> e | f            |
| CONCATENATION                 | ef                 | S --> eA, A --> f      |
| STAR CLOSURE                  | e*                 | S --> eS | ^           |
| PLUS CLOSURE                  | e+                 | S --> eS | e           |
| STAR CLOSURE ON UNION         | (e + f)*           | S --> eS | fS | ^      |
| PLUS CLOSURE ON UNION         | (e + f)+           | S --> eS | fS | e | f  |
| STAR CLOSURE ON CONCATENATION | (ef)*              | S --> eA | ^, A --> fS |
| PLUS CLOSURE ON CONCATENATION | (ef)+              | S --> eA, A --> fS | f |
+-------------------------------+--------------------+------------------------+
```

> **note:** symbol `e` and `f` are terminals, ^ is NULL symbol, and `S` is the start variable

**[ANSWER]**

Now, we can come to you problem.

**a)**  `(0+1)*00(0+1)*`

> **Language description:** All the strings consist of 0s and  1s, containing at-least one pair of `00`.

- Right Linear Grammar:

  S --> 0S | 1S | 00A
  A --> 0A | 1A | ^

  String can start with any string of `0`s and `1`s thats why included rules `s --> 0S | 1S` and Because at-least one pair of `00` ,there is no null symbol. `S --> 00A` is included because `0`, `1` can be after `00`. The symbol `A` takes care of the 0's and 1's after the `00`.
- Left Linear Grammar:

  S --> S0 | S1 | A00
  A --> A0 | A1 | ^

**b)**  `0*(1(0+1))*`

> **Language description:** Any number of 0, followed any number of 10 and 11.
>         { because 1(0 + 1) = 10 + 11 }

- Right Linear Grammar:

  S --> 0S | A | ^
  A --> 1B
  B --> 0A | 1A | 0 | 1

  String starts with any number of `0` so rule `S --> 0S | ^` are included, then rule for generating `10` and `11` for any number of times using `A --> 1B and B --> 0A | 1A | 0 | 1`.

  Other alternative right linear grammar can be

  S --> 0S | A | ^
  A --> 10A | 11A | 10 | 11
- Left Linear Grammar:

  S --> A | ^
  A --> A10 | A11 | B
  B --> B0 | 0

  An alternative form can be

  S --> S10 | S11 | B | ^
  B --> B0 | 0

**c)**  `(((01+10)*11)*00)*`

> **Language description:** First is language contains null(^)  string because there a * (star) on outside of every thing present inside (). Also if a string in language is not null that defiantly ends with 00. One can simply think this regular expression in the form of ( ( (A)* B )* C )* , where (A)* is (01 + 10)* that is any number of repeat of 01 and 10. 
>   If there is a instance of A in string there would be a B defiantly because (A)*B and B is 11.
>   Some example strings { ^, 00, 0000, 000000, 1100, 111100, 1100111100, 011100, 101100, 01110000, 01101100, 0101011010101100, 101001110001101100 ....}

- Left Linear Grammar:

  S --> A00 | ^
  A --> B11 | S
  B --> B01 | B10 | A

  `S --> A00 | ^` because any string is either null, or if it's not null it ends with a `00`. When the string ends with `00`, the variable `A` matches the pattern `((01 + 10)* + 11)*`. Again this pattern can either be null or must end with `11`. If its null, then `A` matches it with `S` again i.e the string ends with pattern like `(00)*`. If the pattern is not null, `B` matches with `(01 + 10)*`. When `B` matches all it can, `A` starts matching the string again. This closes the out-most * in `((01 + 10)* + 11)*`.
- Right Linear Grammar:

  S --> A | 00S | ^
  A --> 01A | 10A | 11S

**Second part of you question**:

```
For a) I have the following:
Left-linear
S --> B00 | S11
B --> B0|B1|011

Right-linear
S --> 00B | 11S
B --> 0B|1B|0|1
```

(***answer***)
You solution are wrong for following reasons,

Left-linear grammar is wrong Because string `0010`  not possible to generate.
Right-linear grammar is wrong Because string  `1000` is not possible to generate. Although both are in language generated by regular expression of question (a).

**EDIT**
Adding DFA's for each regular expression. so that one can find it helpful.

**a)**  `(0+1)*00(0+1)*`

[image: DFA]

**b)**  `0*(1(0+1))*`

[image: DFA]

**c)**  `(((01+10)*11)*00)*`

Drawing DFA for this regular expression is trick and complex.
<sub>For this I wanted to add DFA's</sub>

To simplify the task, we should think the kind formation of RE 
to me the RE `(((01+10)*11)*00)*`  looks like `(a*b)*`

```
(((01+10)*11)* 00 )*
(          a*   b )*
```

Actually in above expression `a` it self in the form of `(a*b)*`
that is `((01+10)*11)*`

RE `(a*b)*` is equals to `(a + b)*b + ^`. The DFA for (a*b)* is as belows:

[image: DFA]

DFA for `((01+10)*11)*` is:

[image: DFA]

DFA for `(((01+10)*11)* 00 )*` is:

[image: DFA]

<sub>Try to find similarity in  construction of above three DFA. don't move ahead till you don't understand first one</sub>

Comment: Using DFA one can easily write grammars: [**Converting a DFA to a Regular Grammar**](http://www.jflap.org/tutorial/fa/dfa2rg/index.html) and [**A regular grammar is either a right-linear grammar or a left-linear grammar.**](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cit596/notes/dave/reggram6.html)

Comment: thanks for the great answer, helped me a lot +1. Is there any tools or programs you are using for drawing or verifying the language description.In addition, if you recommend a book, i'll appreciate it.

Comment: @berkay Thanks! To draw diagrams I use [**dia:**](https://projects.gnome.org/dia/). In [**comments: to my answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770814/drawing-minmal-dfa-for-the-given-regular-expression/14024179#14024179) I suggested some source of learning formal theory. To draw ASCII diagrams I use  [**ascii-flow**](http://www.asciiflow.com/#Draw).

Comment: I've seen a lot of answers on stack and this one by far is the most helpful I've seen, thanks!

Comment: Adding related question link: [converting context free grammer into regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994440/converting-context-free-grammer-into-regular-expression)

Comment: Can the 2nd example be written as: S --> 0S | A | ^, A --> 1B | ^, B --> 0 | 1. If we replace 0A|1A with the closure, we get the same thing

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan honestly I find those rules of converting basic regexes to RLGs intuitive, but converting complex regexes makes me fuzzy. Consider 3rd example `(((01+10)*11)*00)*` you gave. Its closure of concatenation. Basic rule says: `(ef)* = S → eA | ϵ, A → fS`. This does not directly map to `S → A | 00S | ϵ`. There is definitely something more going on here. Some rules / concepts / steps / observations are missing here which should make it more intuitive. Can you point me to that? (I feel there should be more guidelines about how to use those rules in table.)

Comment: @Mahesha999 I did not write it in single step. It took time to analyse you have to read again and again with copy-pencil

Comment: Maybe I'm not reading it correctly, but it seems to me that the first (a) grammar is wrong? The regex `(0+1)` means if 0 is to appear, then 1 must appear together as well. However, `A --> 0A | 1A | ^` means both 0 and 1 can appear independently! This can't be right? e.g. `001` shouldn't be a correct input but only `0001` or `00001` should be. However, in this grammar `001` would be accepted as a correct input. Do brackets not mean "grouping" instead of "one of"?

Comment: @JIXiang "The regex `(0+1)` means if `0` is to appear, then `1` must appear together as well." **No** it means either `0` or `1` , in formal languages the binary operator `+`  stands for union.

Comment: No explanation at all. All you show is how to transform from one form to another with the help of a table. You should explain the idea of how I come to this table, otherwise, nobody is learning anything. "practice without theory is blind"

Comment: @denis631 If things are not clean to you even after given description you should pick a good book and read "regular expression" and "grammar" and "finite automata"  separately then try to understand this *answer*.  - yes, **this is just an answer to the question not a book**  ....... I guess you are at wrong place instead pick a good book on formal languages

Comment: For third regular expression, I came up with somewhat different NFA and grammar as can be seen in this [pic](https://i.postimg.cc/4N7LNNyq/regex-2-g.png). Is it also correct? Also I am not able to see how exactly you were able to directly apply those rules to get left linear grammar. In fact applying rules to get right linear grammar was also difficult / requiring consideration of more facts / not so straight forward. I found `regex to NFA to grammar`-route easy / straight forward instead of directly preparing grammar from regex.

Comment: @anir you should ask [a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Instead of asking in comment.

Answer (score 5):

Rules to convert regular expressions to left or right linear regular grammar
[image: Cheat sheet]

Comment: Copied from [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/68575/steps-to-convert-regular-expressions-directly-to-regular-grammars-and-vice-versa)