# Algorithm for converting any regular expression to right linear regular grammar

Tags: regex, algorithm, grammar

Is there an algorithm to convert any regular expression to a right linear grammar? I am familiar with the algorithm to convert a simple regex to CFG. Right linear grammars have stricter rules. A -> a B or A -> a . This makes constructing the algorithm difficult.

Comment: I don’t remember the normal algorithm for the transformation regex→CFG by heart but doesn’t it produce a linear grammar anyway?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Constructing an equivalent Regular Grammar from a Regular Expression](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13816439/1048572)

Answer (score 3):

There is algorithmic way to convert a Regular Expression(RE)  into Non-Deterministic-Finite-automata(NFA) [[1]](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~torng/360Book/RegLang/RtoN/) [[2]](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~squire/cs451_l6.html)  [[3]](http://www.scribd.com/doc/53090979/2/Program-No-2-ALGORITHM-TO-CONVERT-REGULAR-EXPRESSION-TO-NFA)
Also there is alogorithims to convert DFA into Right-Linner-Grammar (RLG). [[1]](http://www.jflap.org/tutorial/fa/dfa2rg/index.html) [[2]](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/~massey/Teaching/cs301/RestrictedAccess/Slides/301lecture05.pdf)

So of-course their is algorithmic way to convert a RE into RLG.

I think you could like to learn this [Constructing an equivalent Regular Grammar from a Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816439/left-linear-and-right-linear-grammars/13945932#13945932)