# Construct grammar given the following language {a^n b^m | n,m = 0,1,2,...,n <= 2m}

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, computation-theory, context-sensitive-grammar

I just took my midterm but couldn't answer this question.

Can someone please give a couple of examples of the language and construct a grammar for the language **or** 
at least show me how i will go about it?

Also how to write grammar for `L`:

> L = {a<sup>n</sup> b<sup>m</sup> | n,m = 0,1,2,..., n <= 2m }   ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to ask your TA or professor?

Comment: No, we go to StackOverflow for everything these days, including homework solutions.

Comment: it clearly states that it was a question on a midterm. I'm on spring break now so i can't ask my professor. Thanks though.

Comment: @user2197126 actually your question is very good but you asked on wrong form stack-overflow having [one more site](http://cs.stackexchange.com/users/5000/grijesh-chauhan) where you can ask your theoretical questions. This form more related to programming related. Although, *I have added my answer hope you find helpful*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### How to write grammar for formal language?

Before read my this answer you should read first: [**Tips for creating Context free grammars**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126824/tips-for-creating-context-free-grammar/15130451#15130451).

### Grammar for {a<sup>n</sup> b<sup>m</sup> | n,m = 0,1,2,..., n <= 2m }

> What is you language L = {a<sup>n</sup> b<sup>m</sup> | n,m = 0,1,2,..., n <= 2m }   description?

**Language description**:
The language **L** is consist of set of all strings in which  symbols  *`a`* followed by symbols *`b`*, where number of symbol *`b`*  are more than or equals to **half** of number of *`a`*'s.

To understand more clearly:

In pattern **a<sup>n</sup> b<sup>m</sup>**,  first symbols *`a`* come then symbol *`b`*. total number of *`a`* 's is `n` and number of *`b`*'s is  `m`.  The inequality equation says about relation between `n` and `m`. To understand the equation:

```
given:   n <= 2m   
=>       n/2 <= m       means `m` should be = or > then n/2

=>       numberOf(b) >= numberOf(a)/2    ...eq-1
```

So inequality of *n* and *m* says:

> numberOf(**b**) must be *more than or equals* to **half** of numberOf(**a**)

Some example strings in L:

```
b   numberOf(a)=0 and numberOf(b)=1  this satisfy eq-1        
bb  numberOf(a)=0 and numberOf(b)=2  this satisfy eq-1
```

So in language string any number of *`b`* are possible without *`a`*'s. (any string of b) because any number is greater then zero (0/2 = 0).

Other examples:

```
                                     m   n
                                 --------------  
ab     numberOf(a)=1 and numberOf(b)=1 > 1/2   
abb    numberOf(a)=1 and numberOf(b)=2 > 1/2  
abbb   numberOf(a)=1 and numberOf(b)=3 > 1/2  
aabb   numberOf(a)=2 and numberOf(b)=2 > 2/2 = 1  
aaabb  numberOf(a)=3 and numberOf(b)=2 > 3/2 = 1.5
aaaabb numberOf(a)=4 and numberOf(b)=2 = 4/2 = 2
```

Points to be note:

- all above strings are possible because number of *`b`*'s are either equal(=) to half of  the number of *`a`* **or** more (>).
- and interesting point to notice is that total *`a`*'s can also be more then number of *`b`*'s, *but not too much*. Whereas number of *`b`*'s  can be more then number of *`a`*'s by any number of times.

Two more important case are:

- only `a` as a string not possible.
- **note:** null `^` string is also allowed because in `^` , `numberOf(a) = numberOf(b) = 0` that satisfy equation.

<sub>At once, it look that writing grammar is tough but really not...</sub>

According to language description, we need following kinds of rules:

**rule 1**: To generate `^` null string.

```
 N --> ^
```

**rule 2**: To generate any number of *`b`*

```
 B --> bB | b
```

**Rule 3**:  to generate *`a`*'s:
(1) Remember you can't generate too many *`a`*'s without generating *`b`*'s.
(2) Because *`b`*'s are more then = to half of *`a`*'s; you need to generate one *`b`* for every alternate *`a`*
(3) Only `a` as a string not possible so for first (odd)  alternative you need to add *`b`* with an *`a`*
(4) Whereas for even alternative you **can** discard to add *`b`* (*but not compulsory*)

So you overall grammar:

```
   S --> ^ | A | B
   B --> bB | b
   
   A --> aCB | aAB | ^
   C --> aA | ^
```

here `S` is start Variable.

In the above grammar rules you may have confusion in `A --> aCB | aAB | ^`, so below is my explanation:

```
A --> aCB | aAB | ^   
       ^_____^
       for second alternative a 
        
C --> aA    <== to discard `b`    

and  aAB  to keep b
```

let us we generate some strings in language using this grammar rules, I am writing Left most derivation to avoid explanation.

```
  ab     S --> A --> aCB --> aB --> ab                        
  abb    S --> A --> aCB --> aB --> abB --> abb
  abbb   S --> A --> aCB --> aB --> abB --> abB --> abbB --> abbb 
  aabb   S --> A --> aAB --> aaABB --> aaBB --> aabB --> aabb
  aaabb  S --> A --> aCB --> aaAB -->  aaaABB --> aaaBB --> aaabB --> aaabb
  aaaabb S --> A --> aCB --> aaAB --> aaaCBB --> aaaaABB --> aaaaBB 
                                                         --> aaaabB 
                                                         --> aaaabb
```

One more for *non-member* string:

according to language a<sup>5</sup> b<sup>2</sup> = `aaaaabb` is **not** possible. because 2 >= 5/2 = 2.5 ==> 2 >= 2.5 inequality fails. So we can't generate this string using grammar too. I try to show below:

In our grammar to generate extra *`a`*'s we have to use C variable.

```
S --> A 
  --> aCB 
  --> aaAB 
  --> aa aCB B 
  --> aaa aA BB 
  --> aaaa aCB BB  
           ---              
            ^
           here with first `a` I have to put a `b` too
```

While my answer is done but I think you can change `A`'s rules like:

```
A --> aCB | A | ^
```

Give it a Try!!

**EDIT:**
<sub>as @us2012 commented: *It would seem to me that then, `S -> ^ | ab | aaSb | Sb` would be a simpler description*. I feel this question would be good for OP and other also.</sub>

OP's language:

> L = {a<sup>n</sup> b<sup>m</sup> | n,m = 0,1,2,..., n <= 2m}.

@us2012's Grammar:

```
S -> ^ | ab | aaSb | Sb
```

@us2012's question:

> Whether this grammar also generates language L?

Answer is **Yes!**

The inequality in language between number of *`a`*'s = `n`  and  number of *`b`* = m is `n =< 2m`

We can also understand as:

```
 n =< 2m
 
 that is 
 
 numberOf(a) = <  twice of numberOf(b)
```

And In grammar, when even we add *one* or *two*  *`a`*'s  we also add *one* `b` . So ultimately number of *`a`* can't be more then twice of number of *`b`*.

Grammar also have rules to generate. any numbers of *`b`*'s and null `^` strings.

So the simplified Grammar provided by @us2012  is CORRECT and also generates language L exactly.

**Notice:**  The first solution came from derivation as I written in am linked answer, I started with language description then tried to write some basic rules and progressively I could write complete grammar.

Whereas @us2012's answer came by aptitude, you can gain the aptitude to write grammar by reading others' solutions and writing your own for some - just like how you learn programming.

Comment: *let me know if you have more question/doubts regarding this or I made some mistake in my answer, hopefully no*

Comment: Hmm, when I first read the language definition, I thought it included `m = 0,1,2,...,n` , i.e. `m <= n` - but maybe I've been reading it incorrectly.

Comment: Anyways, let's say you're right: It would seem to me that then, `S -> ^ | ab | aaSb | Sb` would be a simpler description - am I missing something?

Comment: @us2012 Yes your grammar is correct. read updated answer.

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer Grijesh - amazing explanation !

Comment: @guipy I am glad  that I could help you. :)