# Formal Context Free Grammar From Context Free Language

Tags: context-free-grammar, automata

How can a formal context free grammar be generated for the following language:

> `{ai bjck | i != j or j != k}`

I have following productions but can't understand it:

```
     S->AX | YC                     unequal b’s c’s or a’s b’s

     A-> aA | e                     0 or more A’s

     C -> cC |e                     0 or more c’s

     B -> bB | e                    0 or more B’s

     X -> bXc | bB | cC             equal b’s, c’s then 1+ b’s, 
                                    1+C’s (i.e. unequal b’s and c’s)

     Y -> aYb | bB | aA             unequal a’s b’s
```

Can anyone help me to understand and solve this problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The language   `L = {ai bj ck | i != j or j != k}` can be simply written as  `L = L1 U L2`  such that  `L1 = {ai bj ck | i != j }`  and  `L1 = {ai bj ck | j != k }`.

In  L<sub>1</sub> there is no constraint on symbol `c` only condition is `numberOf(a)` should not be equals to `numberOf(b)`.  Either `numberof(a)` **>** `numberOf(b)` **or**  `numberof(a)` **<**.`numberOf(b)`. So grammar for this language should be:

```
L1  =>  EX              // L1 is start variable 
E  =>  aEb | A | B
X  =>  C | ^ 
A  =>  aA | a
B  =>  bB | b
C  =>  cC | c
```

In above grammar using E we can generate equal number of `a` and `b` in the pattern of `anEbn`, then to convert this sentimental from into sentence form either `E` has to replaced by `B` or `A` that causes generate a string in the form such that `ai bj` with `i != j` , Using variable `X` any number of `c` can be suffixed to the pattern `ai bj`.

To understand this grammar read: [Tips for creating Context free grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126824/tips-for-creating-context-free-grammar/15130451#15130451) and [Why the need for terminals? Is my solution sufficient enough?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989197/why-the-need-for-terminals-is-my-solution-sufficient-enough/15989998#15989998)

Similarly for L<sub>2</sub> there is no constraint on symbol `a` only condition is `numberOf(b)` should not be equals to `numberOf(c)`.  Either `numberof(b)` **>** `numberOf(c)` **or**  `numberof(b)` **<**.`numberOf(c)`. So grammar for this language should be:

```
L2  =>  YF              // L2 is start variable 
F  =>  bFc | B | C
Y  =>  A | ^ 
A  =>  aA | a
B  =>  bB | b
C  =>  cC | c
```

Now using both of this grammar an introducing a new start variable `S` and two new production rules `S  => L1 | L2` we gets grammar for language  `L = {ai bj ck | i != j or j != k}`.

Comment: Adding one more related link [How to write grammar for formal language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559324/construct-grammar-given-the-following-language-an-bm-n-m-0-1-2-n-2/15578641?noredirect=1#comment28898425_15578641)