# Construct a context-free grammar from this language

Tags: context-free-grammar, automata, context-free-language

Language: {a^m b^n : m ≤ 2n}

If someone could give advice on how to approach this to construct the grammar as well as a solution that would be great and much appreciated!

Comment: Read [Construct grammar given the following language `{a^n b^m | n,m = 0,1,2,…,n <= 2m}`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559324/construct-grammar-given-the-following-language-an-bm-n-m-0-1-2-n-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hints:

1. Start with a grammar for { a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup> | n in N }.
2. The grammar you built in part (1) probably worked by laying down a's on one side of the string and b's on the other. That way, there end up being the same number of a's and b's. Try modifying the grammar so that you put down either one a or two a's each step.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Care to verify for me if it is correct?

I believe then this is the right answer:

S -> e

S -> SaSaSbS

S -> SbSaSaS

S -> SaSbSaS

S -> SaSbS

S -> SbSaS

Comment: @Schwarz That doesn't seem like it works because it allows the a's and b's to be arbitrarily intermixed. There's a much simpler solution that keeps all the a's at the front and the b's at the back.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question and thought it was the {a, b}*. But now I believe this is correct:
S -> e
S -> aSb
S -> Sb