# Why s--> ^ and A --> a ? in Context Free Grammars

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

I've been reading: ["Tips for creating Context free grammar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126824/tips-for-creating-context-free-grammar/15130451#15130451) post for learning purposes and I nearly understand the concept, but I don't quite understand the following.

If we have:

> L = {a<sup>m</sup> b<sup>n</sup> | m >= n}.

I understand this:

```
S --> B
B --> aBb
A  --> aA
```

But what I don't understand is the concept of adding to the end of these particular values, such as:

```
S --> B | ^
B --> aBb | A
A  --> aA | a
```

Why do we add **^** (null), **A**, and **a** to the end of these lines? What do they do and why do we need them?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, a small explanation added in my answer too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need them to be able to construct the strings that are in the language `L`.

`B --> aBb | A` means that if you have a nonterminal `B` it can be replaced by either `aBb` *or* `A`. (Capital letters represent nonterminals and the lower case letters represent terminals).

Let's take a look at the grammar:

```
S --> B | ^
B --> aBb | A
A  --> aA | a
```

**Why do we have a `| ^`?** You need it to be able to generate the empty string. The empty string is clearly part of the language `L` since it contain an equal amount of `a`s and `b`s.

**Why do we have `| A`?** To be able to use the rule for `A`. Now you can replace `B` with `A`  so you can insert either `aA` or `a`. You need this rule to be able to generate strings that have more `a`s than `b`s.

**Why do we have `| a`?** To be able to replace `A` with `a` *without* adding a new nonterminal that need to be replaced.

When I look at this grammar I would say that you need to change `A  --> aA | a` to `A  --> aA | a | ^` to be able to generate strings with an equal amount of `a`s and `b`s. (So you can replace `A` with the empty string (or null) instead of having to add an extra `a`)

Let's say you want to generate the string `aaabb`:

```
S       //You start with S
B       //Rule: S --> B
aBb     //Rule: B --> aBb
aaBbb   //Rule: B --> aBb
aaAbb   //Rule: B --> A
aaabb   //Rule: A --> a
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Can you explain what this symbol means: http://d.pr/i/3YG1 - thanks again.

Comment: @Xiy That sign is the "not equal" sign. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equals_sign#Not_equal)

Comment: @MAV also read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989197/why-the-need-for-terminals-is-my-solution-sufficient-enough?answertab=votes#tab-top) I tried to cove your explanation. also you may like you suggest something :)

Answer (score 0):

The need for the extra ^,A and a is to complete the grammar set.

Thus **A --> aA** takes care of [aa, aaa, aaaa, ...]

**A --> aA | a** takes care of [a, aa, aaa, aaaa, ...]

**B --> aBb** takes care of [ab, aabb, aaabbb, ...]

So, B --> aBb | A should take care of [a, ab, aa, aab, aaa, aaab, aabb, ...]

The only one missing is **^**

So now complete the grammar with **S --> B | ^** [^, a, aa, ab, aaa, aab, aaaa, aaab, aabb, ...]

As you can see, it is not possible to generate the 2nd half from the first half, but it is also a subset of the grammar. So, in order to complete the grammar, that 2nd half is crucial as well. Look at the wikipedia article for clearer examples.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar