# Specifying language for a given grammar

Tags: grammar, regular-language, dfa

DFA problem : Write a complete grammar for L, including the quadruple and the production rules

```
L ={x: ∃y ∈ {a, b}* : x = ay}
```

Answer:

```
G={{S, A}, {a, b}, S, P}
P: S => aA
   A => aA | bA | λ
```

My question is :

1. Why there is `λ` for `A`, but there is no `λ` for `S`?
2. From the language definition, it is any string that begins with an `a` and contains only `a`'s and `b`'s , but why in the answer `A => bA`. Does not it mean that the string starts with `b` if it is `A => bA`?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

> `1.` Why there is `λ` for `A`, but there is no `λ` for `S`?

`λ` nul can be derived from `A` to convert a sentimental from  into sentence. Additionally according to language statement  prefix sub-string `y ∈ {a, b}*`  can be nul (a empty string) e.g. `"a"` is a string belongs to the language. If `y` contain any symbol then length of language will be more than one.

`S` doesn't derive `λ` nul because empty (or say nul string) is not in language. The smallest string in language is single `"a"`.

> `2.` From the language definition, it is any string that begins with an `a` and contains only `a`'s and `b`'s , but why in the answer `A => bA`. Does not it mean that the string starts with `b` if it is `A => bA`?

Note **only**  strings those can derived from start variable `S` are included in language of grammar. You can't start derivation from `A` (that is not start variable). And if you start a derivation from `S` your string will always start with `a` symbol.

I suggest you to read: ["Why the need for terminals? Is my solution sufficient enough?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989197/why-the-need-for-terminals-is-my-solution-sufficient-enough/15989998#15989998) Where I written about basic definition of formal grammar.