# concatenation & union - regular and context free languages

Tags: regular-language, finite-automata, automata, context-free-language

Given L1 context free non regular language.
Given L2 regular language.

Is it possible that L1 U L2 = regular language ?
Also, is it possible that L1*L2 = regular language ?

I think that the 2nd one is impossible. But I'm not sure.

Would love to see an example if one of the abovementioned statements (or both) is/are true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible that `L1 U L2` = regular language ?

Yes, Possible.

A simple case is: if L<sub>1</sub> is sub-set of L<sub>2</sub> then `L1 U L2` will be  regular (`=L2`), for example:  L<sub>1</sub> : { `anbn`  | where `n >= 0` } and `L2  = (a + b)*`

> is it possible that `L1 * L2`  = regular language ?

No, Concatenation of a context-free and Regular will be context-free (because constraint in pattern of L1 is still there in `L1 * L2`).

<sub>Adding a reference: [CS 273: Closure Properties for Context-Free Languages](http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/class/sp08/cs273/Handouts/closure/cfl-closure.html)</sub>

Comment: Thanks :) Just if you can answer fast, what kind of language is : L = {a^ib^j | i != j} ?

Comment: @Rouki I have already answered this here [Why the need for terminals? Is my solution sufficient enough?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989197/why-the-need-for-terminals-is-my-solution-sufficient-enough/15989998#15989998) It is a CFL

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible that `L1 U L2` = regular language ?

Yes, it is possible.
But its always better to take an example:

`L1 = {0*1*}` (regular) and `L2 = {0^n1^n |n>=0}` (context-free).

`L = L1 U L2 = {0*1*}` which is regular language but since **every regular language is context-free**. So, we can say the **union of two always results in context-free language**.

> Is it possible that `L1·L2` = regular language ?

the concatenation of a regular and a context-free language always results in a context-free language.Take the above example again:

`L = L1·L2 = {(0*1*)·(0^n1^n) |n>=0}` (context free).

It can be regular too if for example one of `L1` or `L2` is `Ø`, `L1·L2` will result in `Ø` (regular). But since, all regular languages are context-free, `Ø` is also a context-free.

Check this out: [Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/theory-computation-union-intersection-regular-languages-cfl/)

Answer (score -1):

yes, Concatenation of a context-free and Regular will be regular

take L1= a^nb^n which is CFL and take L2 = Ø which is regular.

**so L1.L2 = (a^nb^n).Ø = Ø which is regular**

Note:  For concatenation of two language must be regular ,
 there has to be atleast one language to be regular.

Comment: You have to prove that the concatenation is regular for *every* possible pair of languages, not just two of your choice.