# Find a grammar for the language

Tags: grammar

{a<sup>m</sup>b<sup>n</sup>c<sup>i</sup> | m > n + i}

I've been trying to figure this out for two hours.  This is what I have so far.

```
//To start with as many a's as you want:  
S => a | aA | aS   
//To ensure an a gets added each time a b or c does so there is always at least 1 more a than b's plus c's.  
A => aBb | aaBbCc | aCc   
B => aBb | lambda  
C => ???
```

I know this is nowhere near correct, which is why I'm asking for help/hints.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grammar is not correct.

Read [Tips for creating “Context Free Grammar”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126824/tips-for-creating-context-free-grammar/15130451#15130451) and linked answers to it, Grammar of your language is

```
S --> aSc | B    // for every `c` there must be a `a`
B --> aBb | A    // for every `b` there must be a `a`
A --> aA  | a    // generate extra `a`
```

Answer (score 0):

Build it up from the inside out:

- B → aBb | ε        -- matches a<sup>i</sup>b<sup>i</sup>
- C → aCc | B       -- matches a<sup>i+j</sup>b<sup>i</sup>c<sup>j</sup>
- S → aC | aS       -- add at least one more a on the front

This is not minimal -- you could do it with 5 rules and 2 non-terminals.