# How to write this CFG?

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, automata, computation-theory

the question is to construct a CFG which generates language

[image]

my solution is: `S -> aSb | aS | bS | a | b`, however, this grammar can also generate strings like `aabb`, so how to do it?

Thanks for help.

Comment: I also explained @: [Tips for creating “Context Free Grammar”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126824/tips-for-creating-context-free-grammar/15130451#15130451) and some of linked answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want a string of `a`'s then a string of `b`'s, with an unequal number of `a`'s and `b`'s. First, let's ignore the equality condition. Then:

`S -> aSb | 0`

will generate all strings that start with `a`'s and then `b`'s. This rule guarantees an equal number of `a`'s and `b`'s, or the empty string. Now what we want is either more `a`'s, or more `b`'s, but not both. Because if we wanted one more `a` AND one more `b`, we'd just apply S again. So we add two new rules:

```
A -> aA 
B -> bB
```

and update `S` to be:

`S -> aSb | A | B`

So now we can add an equal number of `a` and `b`, or add more `a`'s, or add more `b`'s, but not both. This guarantees inequality, so we're almost done. If you don't need the empty string, you can just stop here. For the null string, we can't do:

`S -> aSb | A | B | 0`,

because that can lead to `S -> aSb -> a0b -> ab`, which violates the condition. We also can't do:

`A -> aA | 0`,

because that can produce `S -> aSb -> aAb -> a0b -> ab`. So what do we do? The trick is to force `S`'s later expansions to have at least one `a` or `b`, like this:

```
S -> aSb | aA | bB
A -> aA | 0
B -> bB | 0
```

and that's your solution.