# Constructing a CFG

Tags: context-free-grammar, context-free-language

I literally can't find the answer to this:

L = {vw | v element of {a,b)*, w element of {b,c}*, number of a's <= number of c's}

V --> aV | bV | e

W --> bW | cW | e

But I cannot think of how to combine the construction of the words v and w after one another and keeping in mind the mentioned restriction.. Anyone who could lend me a hand?

Answer (score 0):

As I explained in my answers [tips for writing cfg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126824/tips-for-creating-context-free-grammar/15130451#15130451),  correct approach is first understand all possible patterns of strings in language then write rules.

> What is this language L? In strings of language L:

**1.**  All `'a'`s comes before any `'c'`s
**2.**  Number of `'a'` are less than or equals to  number of `'c'`, So in grammar of L, if a production rule adds one symbol `'a'` then it must also add one or more `'c'`.
**3.**  There is no restriction on occurrence of symbol `'b'`, it can appear anywhere any number of times. 
**4.** Empty (null) string is also belongs to L as number of `'a'` = number if `'c'`== 0. And for same reason a string consists of only symbol `'b'` is also acceptable.
**5.** Any string without `'a'` also belongs L (in other words `(c + b)*` is subset of L).

Now writing grammar rules are easy (read comments to understand each production rules):

```c
S →  BaBSBCB | ^    // add `a` add `C` also, B can be any where so added B   
Z →  CZ | BZ | ^    // to create `(c + b)*`
C →  cC | c         // C always generates one or more `c`s  
B →  bB | ^         // there is no restriction on B it generates `b`s or ^
```