# how to write kleene closure in a production?

Tags: parsing, python-2.7, ply

I'm writing a parser using PLY. The language the parser is for is called s-lang, in the grammar of the language I have the following production:

IdentList → IdentList , identifier ArrayBrackets*

I have already written the production for ArrayBrackets. I tried writing the above production as

```
def p_IdentList(t):
          '''IdentList : IdentList COMMA ID ArrayBrackets*'''
```

I have regular expressions for the vars COMMA and ID. Th problem is that when I include the star, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: main.py:115: Illegal name 'ArrayBrackets*' in rule 'IdentList'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 175, in <module>
```

I tried escpacing the star but it didn't help --- how am I supposed to write the Kleene closure in a production?

[**EDIT**]

After examining [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816439/left-linear-and-right-linear-grammars) closely, I saw that @GrijeshChauhan says,  given a nonterminal e. The Kleene closure of e, that is, e* will be given by the following production

> S → eS | ^

where `eS` is the concatenation of `e` with `S` and `^` is null/empty/epsilon. My question is, does e have to be a terminal?
Can I not apply the same logic to produce a new production for a nonterminal, for example:

```
def p_ArrayBracketsSTAR(t):
'''ArrayBracketsSTAR : ArrayBracketsSTAR ArrayBrackets | '''
```

Comment: The production rule basically says "A IdentList is a list of identifiers, seperated by comma, enclosed by brackets" ?

Comment: ArrayBrackets represents the array subscripting operator, which in this langauge can also be [] (no int between the square braces)

Comment: What it means is that, arrays are part of the identifier list. id[]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps:

```
def p_list(p):
    '''expression   : columnname IN LPAREN listbody RPAREN
    '''
    p[0] = Node('List', leaf=(p[1], tuple(p[4])))

def p_listbody(p):
    '''listbody     : value
                    | value COMMA listbody
    '''
    if len(p) == 2:
        p[0] = [p[1]]
    elif len(p) == 4:
        p[0] = [p[1]] + p[3]
    else:
        raise AssertionError(len(p))

def p_value(p):
    '''value        : SINGLEQUOTEDSTRING
                    | DOUBLEQUOTEDSTRING
                    | NUMBER
    '''
    p[0] = p[1]
```

The tokens for `LPAREN`, `RPAREN`, `ID`, `COMMA`, `...STRING` and `NUMBER` are not shown here and should be obvious. The production rule for `columnname` is irrelevant.

It basically says that a `List` is a `columnname` followed by `IN ( listbody )`. A `listbody` is either a single value or a value followed by more values separated by `COMMA`.

This does not allow an empty list like `mycolumn in []` but you can add a alternative production rule for `list` like `columnname IN LPAREN RPAREN` to cover that case.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is it possible to have the Kleene closure within a production though?

Comment: Not that I know. Your list production rule may look like 'expression : LPAREN listbody RPAREN | LPAREN RPAREN

Comment: I vaguely remember that this is not possible in PLY: `S -> eS|^` is not possible because `S` after `e` is not allowed on the RHS when `S` is also the LHS and there is a disjunction. This may be incorrect though