# Automata theory : Conversion of a Context free grammar to a DFA

Tags: finite-automata, dfa

How to convert a Context Free Grammar to a DFA? This is easy if we have transitions like
A->a B. But when we have the transitions as A->a B c. Then how should we represent it as a DFA

Comment: You can't always convert CFG into DFA, But yes If it is left-linear or right liner then you can. In this case this answer can be helpful [Left-Linear and Right-Linear Grammars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816439/left-linear-and-right-linear-grammars/13945932#13945932)

Comment: and so for A->a B c we cant construct a dfa??

Comment: See correct way it first convert a Grammar into Left-liner  or right-liner then draw DFAs. If it is not possible to convert a CFG into left-linear ( right-liner) then actually grammar generates CFL that is super-set of regular language and DFA  for CFL is not possible. `A -> a B c`  Only a single production rule (not a grammar) so your queston doesn't make sense

Answer (score 2):

There is no general procedure to convert an arbitrary CFG into a DFA. For example, consider this CFG:

> S → aSb | ε

This grammar is for the language { a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup> | n ≥ 0 }, which is a canonical nonregular language. Since we can only build DFAs for regular languages, there’s no way to build a DFA with the same language as this CFG

Answer (score 0):

First, you should convert your language to [CNF (Chomskey Normal Form)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form).
Then steps for conversion are as such:

1. Convert it to left/right grammar is called a regular grammar.
2. [Convert the Regular Grammar into Finite Automata](http://www.sanfoundry.com/automata-theory-regular-grammars/)
   The transitions for automata are obtained as follows
       For every production A -> aB make δ(A, a) = B that is make an are labeled ‘a’ from A to B.
       For every production A -> a make δ(A, a) = final state.
       For every production A -> ϵ, make δ(A, ϵ) = A and A will be final state.

Comment: This procedure will not always work - it may fail because the CFG is for a nonregular language, or because the conversion to CNF produces a non-left-linear or non-right-linear grammar.

Answer (score 0):

- No. For these Grammar no DFA can form.
- why?
- because it requires memory. Memory of occurence of **a**.
- Yes . it is CFL (context free Language).
- We can design a PDA (Push down automata). Here , memory ( STACK is
  use ). for PUSH **a** and POP **b**