# Constructing a right-linear grammar

Tags: grammar, regular-language, computation-theory, formal-languages

I need help to construct a right-linear grammar for the language {w ∈ {a,b}* | w does not end in aa}.

I have constructed the regular grammar for the language {w ∈ {a,b}* | w does not end in aa}, as below

S -> aA | bB | ε

A -> aC | bB | ε

B -> aA | bB | ε

C -> aC | bB

How can I construct a right-linear grammar for the same?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You may find more help related to your topic on [ComputerScience.StackExchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Give it a try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816439/left-linear-and-right-linear-grammars/13945932#13945932

Answer (score 1):

Your grammar is already right-linear, since:

1. For every rule, there is only one non-terminal on the right hand side
2. The non-terminals appear only at the end