# What is this grammar? Context-free or context sensitive

Tags: context-free-grammar, regular-language, automata, formal-languages, context-sensitive-grammar

I am studying Formal Languages and Automata Theory, and I have a question about a problem inside the book that is not answered in it. the question is:

Is this language Context Free, Regular or Context Sensitive?

> L= {a<sup>n</sup>w w<sup>R</sup>b<sup>n</sup>| w is ( a+b )*,  w<sup>R</sup> is reverse of w and n>=0 }

I think this language is context-sensitive, cause it needs at least two stacks for accepting.

May anybody comment on that?

thanks.

Comment: Why do you think it needs two stacks?  Are you sure they cannot be combined into a single stack?

Comment: @ibid: one stack saves to number of a's by pushing a's inside it, one stack saves W, which then pops the W elements to make it reverse and then with each pop of first stack, we put b's at the end to match the number of a's. you see, you cannot merge a's and W into the same stack and know when the W or R(W) is finished. so we need two stacks. may comment?

Comment: I see there's already an answer that makes the point I was making :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Language a<sup>n</sup>w w<sup>R</sup>b<sup>n</sup> is  Context Free language. We can write context free Grammar for this language.

```
S -->  aSb | R
R -->  aRa | bRb | ^
```

`^` is null symbol

PDA: for language a<sup>n</sup>w w<sup>R</sup>b<sup>n</sup>

- push  prefix string `a`<sup>`n`</sup>
- push  `w`
- pop `w` while match each symbol against symbol in `w`<sup>`R`</sup>
- pop all `a` pushed in stack and match against `b` in suffix `b`<sup>`n`</sup>

**Note:** we while processing string of language a<sup>n</sup>w w<sup>R</sup>b<sup>n</sup> through PDA we don't know  where prefix `a`<sup>`n`</sup>  ends then where `w` ends before `w`<sup>`R`</sup> starts so for this language we can't draw a [deterministic model of PDA although Non-deterministic PDA is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617429/ambiguity-in-transition/15661281#15661281). And Important thing is class of non-deterministic PDA is not same as class of deterministic PDA that means [scope deterministic context free languages are not equals to non-deterministic context free.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143186/example-of-non-linear-unambiguous-and-non-deterministic-cfl?answertab=votes#tab-top) (actually deterministic is subset of non-deterministic CFL)

Comment: *let me know my answer helps or you need more details*

Comment: it's a little confusing, I mean, even in an NPDA, we cant know when W is finished to stop popping and start analyzing stack content to have the b suffixes. for example, you have aaa aab baa bbb, you push aaa, then aab, now pop b - a - a - [ now we can't know to stop popping, or start putting b's - thanks

Comment: assume we have aa bbaab baabb bb , the stack operation is put(a,a,b,b,a,a,b) then popping starts like this: if top of stack equals input then pop go to next input and repeat, else if top of stack isn't equal to input, pop stack and put b, until stack is empty... so, this can be accepted by one stack.

Comment: @BardyaMomeni But in  NPDA your have morre then one choice move from one configuration to next configuration, Hence While on one state you can push and pop both for same configuration [Learn PDA for WWr](http://www.eecs.wsu.edu/~ananth/CptS317/Lectures/PDA.pdf) The example will clear you concept between NPDA and PDA.

Comment: thank you Grijesh for your complete, through and accurate answer.

Comment: @BardyaMomeni If you wants I can add good details in answer but you have to wait for that...you may find some other helpful on "Formal Languages and Automata Theory" through my profile...