# finite automaton help, can't understand this concept

Tags: automation, dfa, nfa

Suppose a finite automaton reaches a state s after processing a word w.
How can we tell whether w belongs to the language (or not) of the
automaton if s is final or non-final, and the automation is a DFA or NFA (4
cases).

This has been bugging me.. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Could you add a little more description about the problem you have?

Comment: This was the question I'm stuck on :( It's one of the questions we had in class but I couldn't figure it out. It asked if there's any ways we can tell a word belongs to the language after it reaches a state S.. And if we can tell whether state S is final state or not, and if this automation is DFA or NFA..

Comment: @jason your question is not clear. I would suggest read your text book again. Anyways, -- NFA and DFA are two forms of FA (Finite automata) read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15661281/1673391). And a States in FA can be either Final or Non-Final state. If after procession a string `w` last state is final then string w is considered as accepted. I would suggest you to read [asking questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

A FSA for language *L*, after reading *w*, can stop in a set of states *Q<sub>w</sub>* . *w* is then a member of *L* if and only if there exists at least one final (accepting) state *q<sub>f</sub>* in *Q<sub>w</sub>*. In other words: if the FSA, reading *w*, **can** stop in a final state, then *w* is a member of *L*.

A DFA, reading the same input, will always arrive at the same state; hence the name. So here *Q<sub>w</sub>* always consists of a single state, and the answer is easy: if the state is a final state, than *w* is a member of the language; otherwise, it is not.

NFA are trickier, because if you run it on *w*, it might stop at any state in *Q<sub>w</sub>*. If it is an accepting state, by definition, you know that *w* is a member of *L*. Whew, lucky! But what if, after reading *w*, we reach a non-final state? Can we say, similarly to the DFA, that *w* is not a member of *L*?

Unfortunately, not*. Let's consider these two NFA:

- *NFA<sub>1</sub>*, reading *w*, can stop in *q<sub>nf1</sub>* and *q<sub>nf2</sub>*, both non-final states;
- *NFA<sub>2</sub>*, reading *w*, can stop in *q<sub>nf1</sub>* and *q<sub>nf2</sub>*, but also in *q<sub>f</sub>*, a final state.

Let's say that we fed *w* to our machine and it stopped in *q<sub>nf1</sub>*. What can we say about *w*, without knowing which NFA we are testing? Clearly nothing: *w* is a member of *L<sub>2</sub>*, because if we kept running *NFA<sub>2</sub>* on *w*, sooner or later we might end up in *q<sub>f</sub>* ; on the other hand, *w* is not a member of *L<sub>1</sub>*, because no matter how many times we run *w* through *NFA<sub>1</sub>*, we can only end up in non-accepting states.

So to sum it up:

- DFA, final state: yes
- NFA, final state: yes
- DFA, non-final state: no
- NFA, non-final state: we don't know

**<sup>*</sup>** I assumed that the FSA are black boxes to us, and all we can observe is the word *w* and the state we stop in, *q*. If we knew the structure of the FSA, the NFA case would be much simpler, because we could just check *Q<sub>w</sub>*.