# Difference between transition diagram and finite automata

Tags: finite-automata, automata

I don't know what the differences are between a transition diagram and finite automata. When I google for 'transition diagram', I get state diagrams as a result.

Is there a difference between transition diagrams and finite automata? Or is finite automata a form of transition diagrams?

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer science instead of programming

Comment: [Can anyone please explain difference between finite state machine and finite automata?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22354706/can-anyone-please-explain-difference-between-finite-state-machine-and-finite-aut)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A transition diagram is a way of visually representing finite state machines. It's kind of on the borderline between flowcharts and source code; it contains enough information to completely describe the finite state machine, but when implementing FSMs on a computer, we generally use other representations that are easier for the computer to process.

Answer (score 1):

- A transition diagram for DFA, is a graph shows moment or transition
  between states For each state in Q there is a node represented by the
  circle.3 main components are initial state,final state and inputs

---

- . Finite machine . It is an abstract machine shows finite number
  of    states it  is the simplest machine to recognize patterns.

  [image: Pictorial View]

Hope this will be helpfull for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Finite Automata** is a machine where you feed the machine with some input and the machine produces a respective output(Mealy Machine, Moore machine) or no output at all(Deterministic Finite Automata, Non Deterministic Finite Automata) depending on the machine.

Whereas, a **transition diagram** is used to show the transition from one state to another which is used by all of the above machines. For Example transition from Q1 (initial state) to QF (Final state).

Answer (score 0):

A finite automaton (FA) as name implies **Finite number of states** 
is a simple idealized machine used to recognize patterns within input taken from some character set (or alphabet) .

The job of an FA is to accept or reject an input string depending on whether that string being accepted by FA or not. 
 whereas ;

Transition daigram can be interpreted as a flowchart for an algorithm recognizing a language ; show the transition form one state to other after recieving input strings consists of three things:

**A finite set of states, at least one of which is designated the start state and some of which are designated as final states**