# class of regular language is closed under the union operation

Tags: regex, regular-language, non-deterministic, automata-theory

I am learning regular language under closed union operation theorem.
I got Q,F,q<sub>o</sub>, but I am confuse in getting delta  δ. 
please explain with example specially delta section.

Comment: What are `Q`, `F`, `q₀` and `δ`? If you are reading anything you don't understand, please cite it at least.

Comment: Here I have explained [How does `“δ:Q×Σ→Q”` read in the definition of a DFA (deterministic finite automaton)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870130/how-does-%CE%B4q%C3%97%CE%A3%E2%86%92q-read-in-the-definition-of-a-dfa-deterministic-finite-automat/14940382#14940382)