# Regular expression 0+10*+01*0 convert to NFA

Tags: automata, nfa

My main issue is figuring out the 10* and 01* states.

This is what I have so far: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9Xxn.jpg)

Comment: Are you using `+` where you really mean `|`?   `*+` in a regexp doesn't make a lot of sense (1 or more repeats of 0 or more repeats -- same as just `*`)

Comment: I think those would mean the same thing right? In my textbook they use +

Comment: What does your textbook say what `*` does, and what `+` does?

Comment: `|` normally means alternative, while `+` usually means "repeat the previous thing 1 or more times" -- very similar to `*` which is "repeat 0 or more times"

Comment: The general way of converting an RE to an NFA is first to convert to an NFA with epsilon transitions (which is a trivial and mechanical, though may be tedious and large) and then eliminate the epsilon transitions (which is fairly simple).  Which part are you having trouble with?  It may be easier (or at least less drawing) to remove (some of) the epsilons after intermediate steps of converting to NFA w epsilons

Comment: Was so hoping to get the quote from the textbook... Chances are it is all in there. But books need to be read.

Comment: * is Kleene star, it adds a new start state and makes the new start state the final state. And + acts like a union so it adds a new start state and places epsilon transitions from new start state to the start states.

Comment: My main problem is just figuring out 10* I'm not how to draw this out

Comment: @tadashi [learn approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770814/drawing-minmal-dfa-for-the-given-regular-expression/14024179#14024179)